# Maya Animated Character export for XNA 4.0 problem

Tags: xna, xna-4.0, maya, skeletal-animation, fbx

To begin with, I'm trying to export an animated character in .fbx format from Maya 2013 to XNA 4.0

In Maya, The Model has a basic rig and the animations are in clips made in the Trax editor.

so the issue i'm having is after selecting the model and the root joint and then hitting export in .fbx format, for some reason when i open the exported .fbx file the joint system is detached from the model with no animation.

Btw, i have the animations in clips so that they can be called in code, for example "run","walk","attack".

So, what can i do to solve this problem?

Thank you.